# Problemas ao atualizar dados de registro com dataBinding no Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, gorm

Tenho os seguintes domínios:

```
class Cliente {

    static belongsTo = [empresa: Empresa]

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Empresa {

    /* aqui temos alguns atributos*/

}
```

Ao criar um novo registo da classe empresa consigo fazer de boa:

```
Empresa empresa = new Empresa(params)
empresa.save(flush:true)
```

mas ao tentar atualizar esse registo:

```
Empresa empresa = Empresa.get(params.id)

/* ja tentei de todas essas maneiras */

empresa.properties = params
empresa = params
bindData(empresa,params)
bindData(empresa,params, exclude:[empresa.id]) // ja tentei com include em td tbm
bindData(empresa.properties, params)
```

Também já tentei colocar a propriedade `bindable: true` nas `constraints` mais de nada resolveu, algumas vezes da erro e outras simplesmente não atualiza os dados, versão do `grails: 2.4.2`

Comment: Olá @alleen94, você deve estar falando do bindData (no seu exemplo está escrito dataBind...). E se você fizer o seguinte: verificar exatamente o que está vindo no seu params e atualizar manualmente, propriedade por propriedade, depois dê um save com flush e veja se alguma exceção acontecerá.

Comment: oi @cantoni, então acabei escrevendo errado eu testei com o bindData mesmo, então atualmente eu estou fazendo manualmente propriedade por propriedade, mas usando o databinding não da certo ;s

Comment: Ok @allen94. Você deu uma olhada no conteúdo de params pra ver se tem algo lá que está impedindo que o bindData funcione?

Comment: Então @cantoni pelo que pesquise tem algo a ver com os transient values dos meus dominios, que poder padrão não podem ser bindables, acredito que seja por causa do relacionamento via belongsTo porém não consegui achar nenhum workaround e a unica solução proposta que é setar os atributos com a constraint bindable:true não resolveu meu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido! -> [Duvida no Grails Brasil](http://www.grailsbrasil.com.br/post/show/2738)

Comment: Olá @alleen94, serial legal se você explicasse aqui como foi resolvido. Fazendo um resumo da thread encontrada no Grails Brasil.